# Getting 404 on OData controller once I enable OpenId Connection Authentication in IdentityServer3

Tags: odata, asp.net-identity, openid, identityserver3

I have some OData controllers at routes starting with "/odata". They work fine. When I turn on OpenID Connection Authentication with IdentityServer3 all of a sudden I get 404 on them. Here is how I am doing it:

```
        string connectionString = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["DefaultConnection"].ConnectionString;

        app.Map("/identity", id => {
            id.UseIdentityServer(new IdentityServerOptions
            {
                SiteName = "MyId",
                SigningCertificate = LoadCertificate(),
                IssuerUri = "https://localhost:44308/identity",
                Factory = new IdentityServerServiceFactory().Configure(connectionString),
            });

        });

        app.Map("/odata", appSection =>
            appSection.UseOpenIdConnectAuthentication(new OpenIdConnectAuthenticationOptions
            {
                Authority = "https://localhost:44308/identity",
                ClientId = "MyId",
                RedirectUri = "https://localhost:44308/",
                ResponseType = "id_token",
                MetadataAddress = "https://localhost:44308/identity/.well-known/openid-configuration",
                SignInAsAuthenticationType = "Cookies"
            })
        );
```

I'm using ASP.NET Identity and EntityFramework. The 404 has this exception comment in the html response:

```
<!-- 
[HttpException]: The controller for path &#39;/odata/RETSListings&#39; was not found or does not implement IController.
at System.Web.Mvc.DefaultControllerFactory.GetControllerInstance(RequestContext requestContext, Type controllerType)
at System.Web.Mvc.DefaultControllerFactory.CreateController(RequestContext requestContext, String controllerName)
at System.Web.Mvc.MvcHandler.ProcessRequestInit(HttpContextBase httpContext, IController& controller, IControllerFactory& factory)
at System.Web.Mvc.MvcHandler.BeginProcessRequest(HttpContextBase httpContext, AsyncCallback callback, Object state)
at System.Web.Mvc.MvcHandler.BeginProcessRequest(HttpContext httpContext, AsyncCallback callback, Object state)
at System.Web.Mvc.MvcHandler.System.Web.IHttpAsyncHandler.BeginProcessRequest(HttpContext context, AsyncCallback cb, Object extraData)
at System.Web.HttpApplication.CallHandlerExecutionStep.System.Web.HttpApplication.IExecutionStep.Execute()
at System.Web.HttpApplication.ExecuteStep(IExecutionStep step, Boolean& completedSynchronously)
-->
```

Can anyone see what I am doing wrong here?